# SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql

For some reason this gives me an empty result.

```
Table
ppb_id     ppb_no ppb_date
100        1      (null)
100        2      2013-08-28 00:00:00
101        1      2013-08-28 00:00:00
101        2      2013-08-28 00:00:00

select ppb_id from ppb 
where (ppb_no = 1 and ppb_date is null) and (ppb_no = 2 and ppb_date is not null)
```

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: ppb_Date can't be both null and not null at the same time?

Comment: @Elias not only that but `ppb_no` can't equal 1 and 2 at the same time

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this query?  What do you want the result of your query to be?

Comment: ppb_no = 1 and ppb_date is null is always false and also ppb_no = 2 and ppb_date is not null is always false

Comment: you can not have one row which ppb_no is 1 and ppb_no is also 2.

Answer (score 4):

I would change it to be:

```
select ppb_id from ppb 
where (ppb_no = 1 and ppb_date is null) or (ppb_no = 2 and ppb_date is not null)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are saying you only want results where `ppb_np = 1 AND ppb_date is null` which = 1 result..

Then you say `AND ppb_no = 2 and ppb_date is not null`.

You may want to try `OR` since right now you basically are checking only 1 row after your `AND`

Answer (score 2):

`ppb_date` can't be `null` and `not null` at the same time. It seems like you're looking for the `OR` operator:

```
select ppb_id from ppb 
where (ppb_no = 1 and ppb_date is null) OR 
      (ppb_no = 2 and ppb_date is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have strong reasons to believe that you need an `OR` instead of `AND`.

```
select ppb_id from ppb where (ppb_no = 1 and ppb_date is null) or 
(ppb_no = 2 and ppb_date is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use OR instead of AND if you need two records
    ppb_no = 1
    ppb_no = 2